# ApplicationContext loads when JUnit test run from eclipse, but not from ant build

Tags: java, spring, ant, junit, applicationcontext

Seems weird to me. JUnit test runs fine from eclipse. But when I run from Ant command line, it shows error. Looks like its not loading / application context. Here is the base class of test class.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public abstract class TransactionalTestCase extends StrutsSpringTransactionalTests {

    @Before
    public void onSetUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setupBeforeInitDispatcher() throws Exception {
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, appContext);
    }
```

When I try to print `appContext` in this method, it prints
    org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@9320aa71: startup date xxxxxxx

But it prints null from ant build command line.

I compared the classpath of both eclipse and ant. Both are same. Includes same set of files and folders.

`@ContextConfiguration` not taking effect when I run from ant build?

What else could be wrong?

StrutsSrpingTransactionalTests class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, 
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
@Transactional
public abstract class StrutsSpringTransactionalTests extends StrutsTestCase implements ApplicationContextAware {

    protected ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException {
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out that, the problem is with JUnit versions. Eclipse used Junit4, while ant used Junit3 by default.